# Cannot add records to database from two tables at once

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2013

I written a vb.net program that uses an Access.accdb. There are three tables in the database; Customers, Orders, and another Table just used for populating a ComboBox. I have a form with TextBoxes bound to the CustomersTableBindingSource, and a Navigator Control, and I also have a DataViewGrid which shows all the orders connected with that particular Customers record. When the form is closing it checks to see if the dataset has changes and if so, the offer to save is made. All of this works fine when I make changes on either a Customer record on the form or an Orders record on the DataGridView or do both at the same time. I can even add a new Orders record with no problem and everything will update fine into the database. The problem happens when I try to create a new Customers record AND add Orders to that record at the same time. So long as I just create a Customers record and don't add any Orders it saves just fine, but if I add Orders to it I get -

```
You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'Customers'
```

Of course I can save only the Customers information and then go back and add Orders information later, but that is unsatisfactory. I want to do both at the same time.

This may be relevant code;

```
Private Sub UpDatetheDataBase()
  Try
    Validate()
    CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    OrdersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(CompanyDataSet)

    MsgBox("Update successful")

  Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Update Failed!")
End Try
End Sub
```

And this.

```
Private Sub OrdersBindingSource_AddingNew(sender As Object, e As AddingNewEventArgs) Handles OrdersBindingSource.AddingNew
    'Commit parent records in the dataset before adding new child records
    CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
End Sub
```

Parent Table: Customers
    Child Table: Orders

```
Customers Key Columns: ID
Orders Foreign Key Columns: CustomersID

Both Relation and Foreign Key Constraint
UpDate Rule: Cascade
Delete Rule: Cascade
Accept/Reject Rule: None
Checked Nested Relation
TableAdapterManager UpDateOrder UpDateInsertDelete
```

If I change Accept/Reject Rule to Cascade only the Customers record will be saved but the orders information will not be saved.
I have tried everything I know to do and researched any information I could find and I cannot solve this problem. Please, I would sincerely appreciate any help.

Comment: Presumably you are using `AutoNumber` columns for PKs in Access. When you add a new record to a `DataTable`, it generates a temporary ID. If you create a Customer record you would then use that temporary ID as a FK in the Order records you add.  When you save to the database, it generates the final ID.  If the final ID for the new Customer record is different to the FK in the Order records then those Order records can't be inserted.  What needs to happen is for the final IDs to be retrieved from the database into your `DataSet` for propagation from the Customer table to the Order table.

Comment: Cont.  That doesn't happen by default with Access.  You need to do a bit of work to make it happen.  See here to learn how: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052-Retrieve-Access-AutoNumber-Value-After-Insert&highlight=

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney , and Thanks for the link to the example. I will check it out.